# CSS issue of fixed height and word-wrap

Tags: html, css, html-table, word-wrap

I have a table coded as below;

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
<tr>
    <td class="htTd" width="100" style="word-wrap:break-word">someDynamicLongtextsomeLongtextsomeLongtextsomeLongtextsomeLongtextsomeLongtextsomeLongtextsomeLongtext</td>
    <td class="htTd" width="100" style="word-wrap:break-word">someLongtextsomeLongtextsomeLongtext</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="htTd" width="100" style="word-wrap:break-word">someContentsomeContentsomeContent</td>
    <td class="htTd" width="100" style="word-wrap:break-word">someContent</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In CSS, I have

```
htTd{height:30px}
```

Now the issue is that since the content is dynamic (coming from JSP), the long text does not wrap correctly in IE. In IE, it kind of displays 2 lines and just hides the rest of the content. It wraps correctly in Firefox.

While the issue can be fixed by just removing the height attribute from the CSS...Unfortunately I cannot do that since my CSS is used in many other files and hence I cannot change the CSS.

How do I fix the issue by adding any other CSS attribute in the CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can for example add an id to the table and write something like this:

```
#tableId td{height: auto !important;}
```

or just

```
#tableId .htTd{height: auto} (i would vote for that one)
```

Comment: Actually I tried adding height:auto using the IE Developer toolbar, but for some reasons, it was not working....Not sure if auto is supported by IE...Anyways will also try the other way u have suggested..

Comment: this is the way how I "delete" height and it should work. Ensure that your new declarations overwrites the old one. You can be sure by adding background: yellow to one property and background: red to the second property and see what will be the background color

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the attribute should be break-word. This

```
<td class="htTd" width="100" style="word-wrap:break:word">
```

should be:

```
 <td class="htTd" width="100" style="word-wrap:break-word">
```